# Is it possible to connect to a server with ssh on vscode.dev

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, chromebook

I want to connect to my ssh server using the web version of vscode. It's possible to do this on the desktop version. My chromebook has support for ssh and I can connect to the server using the terminal. The ssh extension gives me this error: "The 'Remote - SSH' extension is not available in Visual Studio Code for the Web.".

Is there any way for me to connect to the server?

I've tried to install the ssh extension and use the remote window to connect to the server. This did not work.